# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'zeros in AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, numpy, api, aws-lambda

I am trying to run a code in AWS Lambda. I have selected Python 3.6/3.7/3.8 as runtime and uploaded the Numpy 1.21/1.18 as layer.

I am used multiple versions of Python runtime and also multiple versions of Numpy.

I get this error when I make a call to the API.

This is the part of the code which is erroring

```
import numpy as np

plnt = np.zeros(shape=(26,1))
```

Below is the error I am getting.

> [ERROR] AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'zeros'
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 234, in load_module
>     return load_source(name, filename, file)   File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
>     module = _load(spec)   File "", line 702, in _load   File "", line 671, in
> _load_unlocked   File "", line 843, in exec_module   File "", line 219,
> in _call_with_frames_removed   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
> line 81, in 
>     plnt = np.zeros(shape=(26,1))

This code works perfectly fine locally and on Heorku. But throws this error when run on the AWS Lambda.

Any suggestions/ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: Did  you try with AWS provided numpy layer?

Comment: i have a lot of other components/libraries which are not there on the AWS layer so I cannot use a combination of both I believe. So I did not use the AWS provided layer.